# Get user information in Twitter API using bearer token

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am using twitter API in my Laravel application. In my app I want to get user name and profile picture when user insert url by. I searched lot but couldn't found. For user info I had to make user login to twitter and connect with my app for access token. I want to use App authorization only so user don't need to login twitter. I found that with Bearer token tweets can be search with this search API

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=twitterapi
```

Is there any API's that I can get User screen name using URL?

I know there may be posts that are similar with this, most answers with usl says "This page doesn't exists" or saying to use Oauth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I was so lazy to read whole documentation. 
[Here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only.html) is everything about App-only authentication. All you need to do is firstly encode consumer key and secret in RFC 1738 and then re-encode them in

```
Base64 "RFC-1738-encoded-consumer-key:RFC-1738-encoded-consumer-secret"
```

format. You will get bearer token credentials like

`eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==` this.

Now you all you need to do is get bearer token with post request with

`https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials` this URL.

Be sure to set header with

```
Authorization: Basic bearer-token-credentials
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 29
```

and you will get Bearer Token in json format.

Now with every request, just send this bearer token in header like

```
Authorization: Bearer bearer-token
```

and you can get data which doesn't require user authentication. For example, if you want to get User data by screen name or id, just send post request in `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=here-comes-twitter-screen-name` URL.

Comment: Is there an example script for that ?

Comment: Sadly not, I had created PHP code in one of my Laravel project when I was working in previous company, but you can create simple Curl request in any programming language.

Comment: @user198989 If you need PHP code, this may help you,

https://hackthestuff.com/article/how-to-integrate-oauth2-twitter-api

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you.  The user gives you the URL `twitter.com/edent` and you want to get the name and avatar from that without using the API. Right?

For the avatar, you can cheat and use https://avatars.io.

Call `https://avatars.io/twitter/edent` and you'll get my avatar image.

Sadly, there's no way to get the name without using the API.  You could try scraping the HTML, but Twitter may change how that work.s

Comment: Thanks for replay. It help me up to some extent. I am ready to use API's but it should not ask user, who are submitting URL to connect twitter with my app. Isn't there any simple access token API that can be used like Youtube provides?